# UITable, How to assign a delegates to UITable In Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a UITable which is linked to my `viewController` which have extensions for `DataSource` and `Delegate`. However when I look at the connections on my view controller they aren't linked and I can't work out how to link them, any help is appreciated.

**IBOutlet**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var locationTableView: UITableView!
```

**Current Code**
extension findCacheViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

```
//Number Of Rows (Return Value)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cacheData.count
}

//Table Content
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = locationTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    let cellData = cacheData[indexPath.row]
    let titleLabelCell = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    let typeLabelCell = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let distanceLabelCell = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel

    if userCurrentLocation == nil {
        titleLabelCell.text = "Location Required"
        typeLabelCell.text = ""
        distanceLabelCell.text = ""
    } else {
        titleLabelCell.text = "\(cellData.memoryTitle)"
        typeLabelCell.text = "\(cellData.memoryType)"
    }

    return cell!
}
```

}

extension findCacheViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

```
//Row Height Based On Condition
//func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    //let cellData = cachedata[indexPath.row]

    //if conditions {

    //}
//}

//Selected Cell Segue Function
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedCell = cacheData[indexPath.row]
    //performSegueWithIdentifier(<#T##identifier: String##String#>, sender: self)
}
```

}

Comment: @Mr.T As you can see from the screenshot (http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=3093afo&s=9#.VoQU6jbxXmI) my tables isnt linked to the delegates or datasource or I can change the labels etc, how do you connect it to the extensions delegates and datasource?

Comment: just drag those outlets to the view controller and release. SImple

Comment: @Mr.T I've tired dragging them into the viewController however a connection isn't being made, is the a certain part I should be dragging it to or just in the Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what the point is of the code you pasted, you said you had issues in the connections in the storyboard? Or did you create the uitableview with code, and if so how did you set the delegate?

In any case you need to `ctrl` and `left click drag` from the uitableview's delegate connection to the correct uiviewcontroller in your storyboard/xib. Alternatively you need to set the delegate by code.

The connection won't happen by itself, you need to do one of the two previous mentioned approaches.

[image: Example of setting delegate to viewcontroller in storyboard]

Comment: I have created a connection from the UITableView to an IBOutlet however I can't get the delegates nor datasource to connect to the ViewController, I have tired dragging but won't connect to the ViewController

Comment: Go to the Connections inspector tab when you have selected your uitableview in your storyboard/xib file. Then `click-drag`from the round circle next to the delegate row, and drop it on the viewcontroller (still in your storyboard, not the .h or swift file). It has a round circle with a white frame as the icon (in your storyboard/xib)

Comment: Yo, thanks I feel so dumb for not doing that hah, I was trying to connect it to the file. Thanks Again

Comment: No problem buddy, I did the same thing when I tried to do it the first time :)